# In the hyperledger composer modelling language can we define a resource with an attribute that is a keyed collection with key-value pairs?

Tags: hyperledger, modeling

Using the hyperledger composer modelling language format, while creating the model file can we define a resource with an attribute that is a keyed collection with key-value pairs? As of now we can only define attributes of type string integer double array enum concept but not a keyed collection such as a map or list.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

For those purposes, i think you can use a concept. From the Hyperledger Composer modeling language [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language):

*"Concepts are abstract classes that are not assets, participants or transactions. They are typically contained by an asset, participant or transaction."*

You would define a concept like this:

```
concept SampleConcept {
 o String firstAttribute
 o String secondAttribute
}
```

Reference it in another asset like this:

```
asset SampleAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  o SampleConcept[] sampleConceptsCollection 
}
```

And populate it like this:

```
{
  "$class": "org.example.basic.SampleAsset",
  "assetId": "1404",
  "sampleConceptsCollection": [
    {
      "$class": "org.example.basic.SampleConcept",
      "firstAttribute": "f",
      "secondAttribute": "d"
    }
  ]
}
```

END EDIT

Not that i know of. What you could do is define an asset that stores you key -> value and then reference that in your other asset. Something like:

```
asset KeyValueAsset identified by keyValueAssetId
{
    o String keyValueAssetId
    o String value
}


asset Something identified by somethingId
{  
    o String somethingId
    --> KeyValueAsset[] keyValueAssets
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something like this too, to be able to have a key:value collection as a field attribute. 

Not sure if the approach mentioned above is efficient, as it entails creating multiple asset instances of KeyValueAsset inorder for the array defined in Something asset to be populated. 

Wouldn't it be more efficient to be able to have something like

o Collection [key:value] someCollection  where key/value can be defined as primitive data types or objects.

Comment: Have you tried with the proposal from my edit? @SowmyaKannan

Comment: Yes I have Fjut . It does work. However if we have a scenario where different instances of Something want different keyvalue collections then this wont work as we can have only one value for a given key. Hence the need to have a key:value collection object as a field attribute.

Comment: Not sure i am following you. With the example from my edit, each instance of sampleAsset has a separate collection of sampleConcepts which have two attributes, essentially mimicking a key-value data structure.

Comment: For eg: One instance of Something say something1 has a KeyValueAsset1 array which contains  instance of KeyValueAsset where  keyValueAssetId = keyValueAssetId1 and value= value1.  Now if we have another instance of Something say something2 which also has a KeyValueAsset2 array which contains an instance of KeyValueAsset where  keyValueAssetId = keyValueAssetId1 but want a different value for this say value2, it wont let me since only one instance of KeyValueAsset where  keyValueAssetId = keyValueAssetId1 can exist. Hope this clarifies what i am saying.

Comment: As i said in my two previous comments, please have a look at my edited answer. SampleConcept is the way to go as it does not have an identifier

Comment: @Fjut this would create the associations, but if you need to look for a given key in the concepts array you would have to iterate over the array, concept by concept, comparing the key. If we could have a key value map we could also use the key as an index.